# Masonry layout for canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can anyone suggest similar to https://github.com/shawnbot/masonic solution, but for canvas?

I need masonry-like layout where image tiles with different sizes will be positioned properly without lots of whitespace.

P.S. Canvas chosen beacause of large data and better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "properly" you mean with minimal white-space and disregarding any rectangle's order, then you are looking for a **`bin packing algorithm'**.

Here's one example (of the many available with a Google search):

https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing